# How do I undo SetSysColors()?

Tags: windows, colors, c++-cli, systemcolors

So I executed:

```
int elements[2] = {COLOR_HIGHLIGHT,COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT};
DWORD newColors[2];

newColors[0] = Color::IndianRed.ToArgb();
newColors[1] = Color::Maroon.ToArgb();

SetSysColors(2,elements,newColors);
```

I thought it might do what I hoped it wouldn't.. but it did so now everything I select looks like this:

[image]

What are the default values for my system to set it back to how it was? I am running Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724940.aspx):

> However, this function affects only the current session. The new colors are not saved when the system terminates.

Just reboot your machine.

Comment: Or even just log out and back in.